# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect cutting off

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cgimage

I am using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect in Swift to create a copy of part of an image at the touch location.

My code works great except when the user touches the edge of the screen and the rect size falls outside the view frame. Instead of returning a square, it returns a rectangle (I assume) from cutting off the amount that lays outside the view. The change is shape throws off the position of the copied image, so it does not align with the lower image.

How do I keep the square shape/size and ignore the bounds, so my images align?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first!.locationInView(mainImageView?.superview)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let crop = CGRectMake(touch.x - CGFloat(brushWidth) / 2, touch.y - CGFloat(brushWidth) / 2, CGFloat(brushWidth), CGFloat(brushWidth))

    let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(screenshot.CGImage, crop)

    if imageRef != nil {
        let newImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!, scale: mainImageView.image!.scale, orientation: mainImageView.image!.imageOrientation)

                let bgImage = UIImageView(image: processedImage)
                bgImage.center = touch
                self.view.addSubview(bgImage)

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is an example of it working:

[image]

Here is an example of it warping the image, because I touched near the edge:

[image]

Comment: Could you simply check whether the touch occurs outside the image, and ignore it if it does?

Comment: It is a smart idea. I thought about it, but technically the touch is inside the image. Part of the rect just falls outside and I would like to still give the user the ability to crop if they touch near the edge.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you know why the yellow rectangle in the second image contains shifted image data? You can see that it and the original image would line up if you moved the rectangle left.

Comment: No idea. I'm pulling my hair out. My guess, the rect size is decreased if it hangs over the frame of the device and the change in shape throws it out of alignment.

Comment: Here's another guess: if you touch outside of the panda photo, then the alignment is done relative to the outside view controller and not the panda view controller. Since the outside view controller is a little wider, the rectangle goes outside. What happens if you make your panda view controller much narrower?

Comment: The weird part is the touch is inside. It's the center of that square. Possibly offsetting the position of the created view based on the amount the rect hangs over might work, but seems like there has to be an easier fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(screenshot.CGImage, crop) does indeed return a cropped version. Here is the relevant comment from the documentation:

> Quartz performs these tasks to create the subimage:
>
> - Adjusts the area specified by the rect parameter to integral bounds by calling the function CGRectIntegral.
> - **Intersects the result with a rectangle whose origin is (0,0) and size is equal to the size of the image specified by the image parameter.**
> - References the pixels within the resulting rectangle, treating the first pixel within the rectangle as the origin of the sub image.

A simple way to solve this is to adjust the position of the resulting UIImageView so it is correct for its size. Here is the relevant calculation:

```
let screenshotBounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenshot.size.width, screenshot.size.height)
let cropIntegral = CGRectIntegral(crop)
let cropIntersection = CGRectIntersection(cropIntegral, screenshotBounds)
bgImage.center = CGPoint(CGRectGetMidX(cropIntersection), CGRectGetMidY(cropIntersection))
```

cropIntersection is the bounding rectangle of our extracted image (following the first two steps given in the documentation). Therefore, we can use it to position the imageView to the same place in the original image.

Comment: Works perfect! I appreciate you integrating my variables as well!